# clear gridview in vb.net

Tags: c#, vb.net

i am trying to clear the grid view using the following code but it is not working:

```
da.Fill(dt);

 GridView1.DataSource = dt;

 GridView1.DataBind();

 DataSourceOperation.Delete=GridView1;

 connection.Close();`
```

please tell me what is wrong in this statement.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
GridView1.DataSource = null;
```

`DataSourceOperation` is an enumeration so you can't set an Enumeration to be a `GridView`. How does this even compile?

Answer (score 0):

How about trying this:

```
dt.Rows.Clear();
GridView1.DataBind();
```